# task.getResult().exists() always passes me to the same if condition

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

The if statement `if(task.getResult().exists())` always passes me to else part and Toast "Data does not exist". No matter if I login with an account, who has created data in user_id directory.

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("users").document(user_id).get().addOnComp 
                                 leteListener(new 
             OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> 
        task) {

                if(task.isSuccessful()){

                    if(task.getResult().exists()){


                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Data 
         exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else {


                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Data does 
        not exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }


                } else {

                    String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                    Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this,"Firestore 
        retrieve error" +  error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Check the value of user_id, by adding Log in else block or with a debugger. If you fetch this user_id on app's startup, it might be null because firebase auth have not finished the actual authentication. It must be that user_id and the actual document id don't match

Comment: Turns out that I created a collection called "Users", but here I tried accessing the "users". It's weird that they do not point this as error tho.

Comment: Great that you managed to solve the problem :) It is not so weird, sometimes it is useful to check if a document exists or not. And access collections and documents that dont exist currently to write new data